# How to use *this from inside a class member function to swap its own address with the address of a passed pointer (of same type)

Tags: c++

Okay, here is a class named **dLinikedList** (yeah yeah, I know I should use STL containers):

```
class dLinkedList
{
public:

    //constructors will go here
    explicit dLinkedList(const int value)
    {
        createFirstNode(value);
        nodeCount = new size_t;
        updateNodeCount();
    }
    
    dLinkedList(const dLinkedList &rhs)
    {
        Node *temp = rhs.head;

        createFirstNode(temp->data);
        nodeCount = new size_t;
        updateNodeCount();
        
        temp = temp->next;
        while(temp)
        {
            push_back(temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        
        updateNodeCount();
    }
    
    explicit dLinkedList(size_t numberOfNode, int initializationValue)
    {
        createFirstNode(initializationValue);
        for(size_t i = 1; i < numberOfNode; ++i)
            push_back(initializationValue);
        
        nodeCount = new size_t;
        updateNodeCount();
    }

    //class destructor will go here
    ~dLinkedList()
    {
        clear();
        delete nodeCount;
        nodeCount = nullptr;
    }

    //member functions will go here
    void push_back(int);                    // will attach a new node at the end of the list
    void push_front(int);                   // will insert a new node at the beginning of the list
    bool insertNode(int, int, bool, bool);  // will insert a new node after the existing node (true = first occurrence from the head with value int OTHERWISE if false, then from the tail.)
    bool deleteNode(int, bool);             // will delete the existing node (true = first occurrence from the head with value int OTHERWISE if false, then from the tail.)
    void pop_back();                         // will delete the last node in the list and return the value of the internal data
    void pop_front();                       // will delete the first node in the list
    size_t size();                          // will return the number of nodes/elements - experimental feature
    void printList(bool);                   // will print the values of the data - (true for ordered list, false for reverse ordered list)
    void swap(dLinkedList &rhs);             // will swap this linked-list with rhs

    //operator overloading go here
    dLinkedList& operator = (const dLinkedList &rhs);
    dLinkedList& operator + (const dLinkedList &rhs);
    dLinkedList& operator += (const dLinkedList &rhs);
    dLinkedList& operator >> (const size_t numberOfNodes);
    dLinkedList& operator << (const dLinkedList &rhs);

private:
    //defining the double linked-list structure
    struct Node
    {
        int data; //this is a generic place holder - will be replaced later with some actual data-structures
        Node *next;
        Node *previous;

        explicit Node(int x) : data(x), next(nullptr), previous(nullptr) {}
    };

    //member functions go here
    void createFirstNode(int val);  //will create the first node when the list is empty
    void clear();  // will be called when class destructor is called
    void updateNodeCount(); // keeps the nodeCount variable up-to-date
    bool empty(); // returns true if the list is empty

    //some experimental utility functions for internal use
    void ectomizeAndClip(Node*);
    Node *detectData(int, bool);
    void insertBefore(Node*, int);
    void insertAfter(Node*, int);

    //member variables go here
    Node *head {nullptr};
    Node *tail {nullptr};
    size_t *nodeCount {nullptr}; //experimental feature
    
};
```

There is this member function, currently implemented as:

```
void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList &rhs)
{
    dLinkedList temp {rhs};
    rhs.clear();
    
    Node *traverser = head;
    while(traverser != nullptr)
    {
        rhs.push_back(traverser->data);
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
    
    clear();
    traverser = temp.head;
    while(traverser != nullptr)
    {
        push_back(traverser->data);
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
}
```

Obviously, as the length of the list grows, this operation takes significant amount of time.
Here is what I am thinking (if at all possible - in order to minimize the time to execute in cases of larger lists):

```
void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList *rhs)
{
// what I am planning to achieve is simply swap the address mutually.
    dLinkedList *temp {rhs};
    rhs = this;
    this = temp;
}
```

But this code is not working and is giving an error as follows:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|
```

I want to clear my doubts/misconception about whether this is achievable? If yes, what will be the code.

Comment: You write `void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList &rhs)` in one place and `void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList *rhs)` in the other place. Make up your mind.

Comment: No it's not achievable, but there is a better alternative to your current code, which is to swap each member of `*this` with the same member of `rhs`. If you post your class, I'll post the code.

Comment: You cannot "swap the address". Object's address is its immutable property. The normal and expected way to make a program-defined type swappable is to provide a **non-member** function `swap` in the same namespace as the type.

Comment: *"`rhs = this;`"* -- here is another problem with your idea. This gives `rhs` a new value, but `rhs` is local to the function call. When the function ends, so does the effect of this assignment. Even if your function could compile, it would effectively be a no-op.

Comment: @john How do I post my code?

Comment: @SogaBan Edit the question you have already posted.

Comment: @john Should I post the whole code or only the class?

Comment: @SogaBan Just the class, in fact probably just the `class { ... };` declaration. That should be enough to get an idea of how the class is used and implemented.

Comment: @john - done. Please suggest/advice;

Comment: @SogaBan See my updated answer (which basically hasn't changed, I've just filled in some detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class consists of three pointers, just swap those pointers. This is very efficient and doesn't depend on the size of the list.

Like this

```
void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList &rhs)
{
    std::swap(head, rhs.head);
    std::swap(tail, rhs.tail);
    std::swap(nodeCount, rhs.nodeCount);
}
```

Sometimes this approach won't work if the nodes contain pointers back to the containing object, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: What do you mean by "nodes contain pointers back to the containing object"?

Comment: @SogaBan I mean a pointer whose address is dependent on the address of the list object itself. If one of your nodes has such a pointer then moving that node to another list will not work since that pointer will still be pointing at the old list. There is actually a well known implementation of a doubly linked list that has this feature, but not yours I think

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a constant/immutable pointer `dLinkedList* const this` and can not be modified by `this = temp`.

Use the standard swap

```
void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList *rhs)
{
  std::swap(*this, *rhs);
}
```

The function parameter is rather incorrect and should be

```
void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList &rhs)
{
  std::swap(*this, rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `dLinkedList` you want to swap as a reference in swap function and just swap the `head`s of `this` and `rhs` using `std::swap`.

```cpp
void dLinkedList::swap(dLinkedList& rhs) {
    std::swap(this->head, rhs.head);
}
```